# Why does web host recommend not to use phpmyadmin but instead use workbench (for "security" reasons)?

Tags: security, phpmyadmin, webserver, mysql-workbench

Do you think they are getting a kickback from Oracle (the makers of Workbench), or is there a valid reason to consider phpmyadmin to be less secure than (the paid) workbench application?

Answer (score 2):

The main issue using phpmyadmin is related to MySQL users allowed ip's.

For example; Let assume that you have installed MySQL with default configuration and you set **123456** as a password (which is not good). As you know root login are only allowed when source ip is 127.0.0.1 ( default configuration ). In this scenario, your database server will be secure even if 3306 port can be accessible from internet. Because of client have to initiate connection from 127.0.0.1 which is localhost.

If you've installed phpMyAdmin on your server, this source ip protection will be useless. Because hackers will be able to initiate MySQL connection from localhost through PHP/Apache.

In order to keep your database server secure, use SSH Tunneling feature of workbench . Documentation for ssh tunneling can be found here; https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/9330/2180/how-to-connect-to-database-using-workbench-mysql-client

Comment: There are a lot of errors in your logic. How about a more complete answer describing security issues in a server not set up by an amateur. The issue you described, `hackers will be able to initiate MySQL connection from localhost through PHP/Apache`, is complete bogus, this could not occur on a correctly set up web server with adequate security measures. Please provide a valid response since your response is false and just an advertisement for workbench.

Comment: It's an attempt to give a short answer why MySQL Workbench (or similar programs) are safer compared to PMA. That doesn't necessarily mean to have a full article about all the problems that can arise when using PMA or webpage in general for accessing backend structures. (+1 for explicitly refering to SSH connections).